# SqlExceptionHelper : ERROR: column user0_. does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

При тестировании oauth2 отправляю post метод

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

данные есть в БД все должно отрабатывать корректно. Basic Auth также указан.
сущность User представлена классом

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "public")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements Serializable {

    public User(User user) {
        this.username = user.getUsername();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.email = user.getEmail();
        this.enabled = user.isEnabled();
        this.accountNonExpired = user.isAccountNonExpired();
        this.credentialsNonExpired = user.isCredentialsNonExpired();
        this.accountNonLocked = user.isAccountNonLocked();
        this.roles = user.getRoles();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String username;
    @Column
    private String password;
    @Column
    private String email;
    @Column
    private boolean enabled;
    @Column
    private boolean accountNonExpired;
    @Column
    private boolean credentialsNonExpired;
    @Column
    private boolean accountNonLocked;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "role_user", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private List<Role> roles;

}
```

Почему такая ошибка не могу понять

```
ERROR: column user0_.account_non_expired does not exist
  Подсказка: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "user0_.accountnonexpired".
```

откуда берется account_non_expired?

в БД table users

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку имя поля в `java` указано по-верблюжьи (`CamelCase`), то к нему нужно добавить его именование в SQL. Примерно так:

```
@Column(name = "accountnonexpired")
private boolean accountNonExpired;
```